# Terminal blank and not executing commands

Tags: command-line, bash, python, django

I have been trying to set up a Python virtual environment with Django and pip on my Ubuntu VM through the terminal using these [guidelines](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/requirements.html#installing-the-software).

I last logged out of the terminal after trying to install the virtual wrapper with no success, with the command:

```
source virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Now I can't do anything, it doesn't execute anything and just displays nothing like this:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried restarting my computer but it has had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

On that page they're suggesting to add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

I suppose you did that and now one of the two commands (`eval "$(pyenv init -)"` or `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"`) is spawning a subshell which isn't either exiting nor outputting anything.

Remove `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` and `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` from `~/.bashrc` and test the commands separately to see what's wrong with them:

```bsh
pyenv init -
pyenv virtualenv-init -
```

---

As per your comment you added `source virtualenvwrapper.sh` in an infinite loop to your `~/.bashrc`, so that's what's actually halting the terminal.

Running `source` has the effect of running the target file, applying potential modifications to the current shell, and you just need to run it only once:

```
source virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Thanks I think figured it out, similar to what you said but further down the page it says to add the command  source virtualenvwrapper.sh to bash and it put it into a infinite loop i think.
I also had to switch profile from default to user profile before i could break the loop with Ctrl + c

Comment: @2155569 `source`ing a file in a loop makes no sense at all by the way, `source` has the effect of running the target file, applying potential modifications to the current shell. Just `source` it once: `source virtualenvwrapper.sh`.